# List required packages by introspection in Python

Tags: python, pip, conda, introspection, requirements.txt

How can I list the requires packages by introspection from running Python or IPython instance?

I often start development from a very loaded conda environment that has the full Anaconda distribution and a whole lo more installed. When I wish to share code I would like to be able to spit out a `requirements.txt` for pip or `environment.yml` for conda consisting only of the packages currrently loaded in the interpreter.

How can I do this?

Comment: To build the ralation from loaded modules to package would be a complex task. In general I advise to start developing with an empty environment.

Comment: @Klaus doesn't conda maintain such a mapping?

Comment: It is easy to get the names of the modules loaded, but they are not necessarily the names as required for conda or pip. And a lot of built-in and "private" modules will be in the list.

Comment: @Klaus conda & pip have to maintain their own module->pacakage mappings in order for their remove commands to work. It should be possible to access that programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the python builtin package [modulefinder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/modulefinder.html) to test your script for modules. Something like:

```py
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder

finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script('bacon.py')

print('Loaded modules:')
for name, mod in finder.modules.items():
    print('%s: ' % name, end='')
    print(','.join(list(mod.globalnames.keys())[:3]))

print('-'*50)
print('Modules not imported:')
print('\n'.join(finder.badmodules.keys()))
```